# django how to Pass an id from a template to a view

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I want to update an item and I have this views.py

```
def update(request,cl_itemid):
if request.method == "POST":
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    resolve_item = get_object_or_404(Clearanceinsert, pk=cl_itemid)
    cursor.execute("select resolve_clearance_item('"+resolve_item+"')")
    return render(request, 'clearance/index.html')
else:
    return render(request, 'clearance/index.html')
```

when I clicked an item, the data goes to my def update then run this postgres function

let's say I have this list of items

test001 | [update](https://google.com)

test002 | [update](https://google.com)

here's my template

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
      <th>cl_itemid</th>
      <th colspan="2">Actions:</th>
  </tr>
{%for data in data%}
  <tr>
      <td>{{data.cl_itemid}}</td>
      <td><a href="{% url 'update' data.cl_itemid %}">Update</a></td>
  </tr>
{%endfor%}
</table>
```

if this is not possible then maybe someone can recommend an alternative solution

Comment: Please don't use string interpolation to create SQL queries, it makes you vulnerable to **SQL Injection**. Also `resolve_item` is an instance of `Clearanceinsert` you should instead use a value from one of it's columns if you want to create a raw query (Plus you aren't specifying any context while rendering your template why do expect there to be a `data` in the context magically)...

Comment: sorry I'm new in django I understood the sql injection based on what I read so far, but the rest is quite overwhelming. I thought resolve_item is just a name of the object when I try to call it. what do you mean by context while rendering your template

Answer (score 0):

if u want to update something do this:

```
def update(request, id):  
    machine = Model.objects.get(id=id)  #Add here your model name
    form = Form(request.POST,instance=machine)  #Add here form name
    if form.is_valid():  
        form.save()  
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')  #Add your path, where you want to go after update
    return render(request,'edit.html',{'machine': machine}) #Add here your context
```

In your template:

```
<form method="post" class="post-form" action="/appaname/update/{{ machine.id }}">   #Add here context name
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
      <th>cl_itemid</th>
      <th colspan="2">Actions:</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>{{data.cl_itemid}}</td> #Add here context name.id
      <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Update</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</form>
```

Add this inside url:

```
path('update/<int:id>',views.update)
```

By doing this, you can update anything.
hope it will solve your problem

Comment: i want to use forms or modelform but my boss wants me to use his postgre function thank you thou for the answer